# Find channel entries with a field value greater or less than

Tags: expressionengine

I figured there'd be an easy way to pull entry values via a field.  I'm building a site that has a basic search for a price (for property) and was hoping to do something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="property" search="price < 200000"}
  <blah />
{exp:channel:entries}
```

However it seems I can only search for a value equal or not equal to a field value.  Is that right or am I being particularly thick this weekend? I'm relatively new to EE, so apologies if it's a stupid question ...

Assuming I'm not being thick, are there any plug ins that would do that?

Comment: You might want to move this to the EE StackExchange site:  http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com